# Read text file into dictionary removing heading/trailing newlines

Tags: python, dictionary, text-files

This will be much easier to understand if I just show you the text file I'm working with and the code I have. Here's the text file, called employees.txt:

```
7
John
Doe
33
272838
M
Mary
Johnson
38
3849383
.....
```

---

Now I have two functions. Here they are:

```
def employee_write(file):
    employee_dict = {}
    employee_dict["First"] = file.readline()
    employee_dict["Last"] = file.readline()
    employee_dict["Experience"] = file.readline()
    employee_dict["ID"] = file.readline()
    employee_dict["Gender"] = file.readline()
    return employee_dict

def main():
    file = open("employees.txt", "r")
    n = int(file.readline())
    x1 = employee_write(file)
    employee_list = []
    for i in range(n):
        employee_list.append(x1)
        x2 = employee_list
    print(x2)
```

Unfortunately, when I print out the list of dictionaries, the values that I attached to the keys in the first function all come out with a newline character attached, like this:

```
[{'ID': '272838\n', 'Last': 'Doe\n', 'First': 'John\n', 'Experience': '33\n', 'Gender': 'M\n'}, {'ID': '272838\n', 'Last': 'Doe\n', 'First': 'John\n', 'Experience': '33\n', 'Gender': 'M\n'}, {'ID': '272838\n', 'Last': 'Doe\n', 'First': 'John\n', 'Experience': '33\n', 'Gender': 'M\n'}, {'ID': '272838\n', 'Last': 'Doe\n', 'First': 'John\n', 'Experience': '33\n', 'Gender': 'M\n'}, {'ID': '272838\n', 'Last': 'Doe\n', 'First': 'John\n', 'Experience': '33\n', 'Gender': 'M\n'}, {'ID': '272838\n', 'Last': 'Doe\n', 'First': 'John\n', 'Experience': '33\n', 'Gender': 'M\n'}, {'ID': '272838\n', 'Last': 'Doe\n', 'First': 'John\n', 'Experience': '33\n', 'Gender': 'M\n'}]
```

How do I fix that?

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, please accept, so that we can move on.

Answer (score 4):

Whereever you read using `readline()`, use `readline().strip()`

Answer (score 1):

`.strip()` without an argument strips all spaces/tabs/newlines

Answer (score 1):

[community wiki, because this is really a long comment]

(1) I'd call your function `employee_read` and not `employee_write`.

(2) Rather than all that duplication, I might do:

```
def employee_read(source):
    keys = "First Last Experience ID Gender".split()
    employee_dict = {key: next(source).strip() for key in keys}
    return employee_dict
```

(3) Your main function could instead be written

```
def main():
    with open("employees.txt") as fp:
        n = int(next(fp))
        employees = [employee_read(fp) for i in range(n)]
    print employees
```

which gives

```
>>> main()
[{'Gender': 'M', 'Last': 'Doe', 'ID': '272838', 'Experience': '33', 'First': 'John'},
{'Gender': 'F', 'Last': 'Johnson', 'ID': '3849383', 'Experience': '38', 'First': 'Mary'}]
```

Comment: Up voted because there are so many sweet bits of code in here ! On my way to learn more about next() , Thanks for sharing this!

Answer (score 0):

Append `.rstrip('\n')` to your `readline` calls to sanitize the newline out of the line.