# I need help pulling out specific data from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, text-files

I have a text file that lists the first and last names of a set of employees, their ID numbers, genders and years of experience. The first line contains the number of employees. It's called employees.txt. Here it is:

7

John

Doe

33

272838

M

Mary

Johnson

38

3849383

F

Opie

Dog

6

839293

M

Missy

Dog

4

238392

F

John

Bla

28

834282

M

Amelia

Spien

2

5789812

F

Shane

CasenStien

2

567891

M

---

I want to organize this information into a list of dictionaries and then find all the female employees and print out their first and last names. I can get the list of dictionaries to work, but I'm getting an error when I try to find and print out the names of the female employees. Here's my code:

```
def employee_write(file):
    employee_dict = {}
    employee_dict["First"] = file.readline().strip()
    employee_dict["Last"] = file.readline().strip()
    employee_dict["Experience"] = file.readline().strip()
    employee_dict["ID"] = file.readline().strip()
    employee_dict["Gender"] = file.readline().strip()
    return employee_dict

def female_print(x2):
    for term in x2:
        for word in employee_dict:
            if employee_dict["Gender"] == "F":
                print(employee_dict["First"])
                print(employee_dict["Last"])

def main():
    file = open("employees.txt", "r")
    n = int(file.readline())
    x1 = employee_write(file)
    employee_list = []
    for i in range(n):
        employee_list.append(x1)
        x2 = employee_list
    print(x2)
    female_print(x2)

main()
```

What is my error here? The female_print() function is not working because it says that the name 'employee_dict' is not defined. What's the problem?

Comment: Please add the error you see to the question.

Comment: what about this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15440785/read-text-file-into-dictionary-removing-heading-trailing-newlines/15441090#15441090

Comment: It says that the name 'employee_dict' in the 'function female_print(x2)' is not defined.

Comment: That's because you didn't 1) pass it in, or 2) declare it as a global

Comment: So how do I fix that, Moshie?

Answer (score 1):

I have some trouble to understand your variables naming and usage, so I've simplified it a little:

```
def employee_write(file):
    employee_dict = {}
    employee_dict["First"] = file.readline().strip()
    employee_dict["Last"] = file.readline().strip()
    employee_dict["Experience"] = file.readline().strip()
    employee_dict["ID"] = file.readline().strip()
    employee_dict["Gender"] = file.readline().strip()
    return employee_dict

def female_print(employee_list):
    for employee in employee_list:
        if employee["Gender"] == "F":
            print(employee["First"])
            print(employee["Last"])

def main():
    file = open("employees.txt", "r")
    n = int(file.readline())
    employee_list = []
    for i in range(n):
        employee_list.append(employee_write(file))
    print(employee_list)
    female_print(employee_list)

main()
```

which yields

```
[{'Gender': 'M', 'Last': 'Doe', 'ID': '272838', 'Experience': '33', 'First': 'John'}, {'Gender': 'F', 'Last': 'Johnson', 'ID': '3849383', 'Experience': '38', 'First': 'Mary'}, {'Gender': 'M', 'Last': 'Dog', 'ID': '839293', 'Experience': '6', 'First': 'Opie'}, {'Gender': 'F', 'Last': 'Dog', 'ID': '238392', 'Experience': '4', 'First': 'Missy'}, {'Gender': 'M', 'Last': 'Bla', 'ID': '834282', 'Experience': '28', 'First': 'John'}, {'Gender': 'F', 'Last': 'Spien', 'ID': '5789812', 'Experience': '2', 'First': 'Amelia'}, {'Gender': 'M', 'Last': 'CasenStien', 'ID': '567891', 'Experience': '2', 'First': 'Shane'}]
Mary
Johnson
Missy
Dog
Amelia
Spin
```

Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You have two (major) issues here.  For one, you're not actually reading in the whole file.  You're reading in the first record (as x1) then appending that record to a list N times.  You can see from the print that you're only getting one record.

Also, your print_female function is referencing a non-existant variable "employee_dict" - you probably need to define that somewhere.  Perhaps you meant to use "term"?  This throws a stack trace.

If you fix these two issues, the basic premise of your code is sound.

Answer (score 0):

In `main`, the function `employee_write`, (which should probably be called `employee_read` instead) is only called *once*.

Try something like this instead:

```
In [1]: with open('employees.txt', 'r') as ef:
    txt = ef.read()
   ...:     

In [2]: lines = txt.split()

In [3]: records = [lines[i:i+5] for i in xrange(1, len(lines), 5)]

In [4]: records
Out[4]: [['John', 'Doe', '33', '272838', 'M'], ['Mary', 'Johnson', '38', '3849383', 'F'], ['Opie', 'Dog', '6', '839293', 'M'], ['Missy', 'Dog', '4', '238392', 'F'], ['John', 'Bla', '28', '834282', 'M'], ['Amelia', 'Spien', '2', '5789812', 'F'], ['Shane', 'CasenStien', '2', '567891', 'M']]

In []: for r in records:
    print r
   ....:     
['John', 'Doe', '33', '272838', 'M']
['Mary', 'Johnson', '38', '3849383', 'F']
['Opie', 'Dog', '6', '839293', 'M']
['Missy', 'Dog', '4', '238392', 'F']
['John', 'Bla', '28', '834282', 'M']
['Amelia', 'Spien', '2', '5789812', 'F']
['Shane', 'CasenStien', '2', '567891', 'M']
```

N.B.: this code *assumes* that the input file is formatted correctly!

Comment: Note that the data file has a header line at the start containing the number of records.

Comment: Oops. Fixes off-by-one error because of the number of records. Thanks DSM!